# put a value of localstorage into value input form

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i'm a beginner of javascript and html5. I want put a value of `localStorage` into value input form.

I have an HTML page:

```
<form class="row g-3" method="GET">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="s1" class="form-label">Nome</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="s1" value=" " >
  </div>
</form>

<script src="script.js">
  var savedValue = window.localStorage.getItem("email") || "";
  document.getElementById("s1").value = savedValue;
</script>
```

How can I put the value from `localStorage` into the input?

Comment: be specific. what kind of input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script tag names a src, even though it seems that the script you want to run is already there in the body. Because of the src, it is being ignored. Just remove the src attribute. Also, I would recommend adding a `console.log` for debugging.

```js
<script>
  var savedValue = window.localStorage.getItem("email") || "";
  console.log('setting value for s1:', savedValue);
  document.getElementById("s1").value = savedValue;
</script>
```